# How to filter rows based on column value while running a loop in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset with 13 features and 1 label column with only two outcomes Income =< 50k or > 50k. 
I am trying to see the distribution of values for each feature for the entire dataset vs the same feature but only with >50k cases to see how the distribution changes or not for that given subset.
if i do:

```
filtertable = table[table[column] == criteria]
```

that works well to get the subset

However when used inside a function:

```
def comparacion(tabla, columna, criterio):
    completa = {}
    criteria = {}
    datos = tabla[tabla[columna] == criterio] #<- here is the problem
    datos = tabla.drop(columna, axis=1)
    titulos = datos.columns
    for tit in titulos:
        completa[tit] = 
        (tabla[tit].value_counts().astype(float))/len(tabla[tit])
        criteria[tit] = 
        (datos[tit].value_counts().astype(float))/len(datos[tit])
    return completa, criteria
```

For some reason the filtering does not work, any ideas what could it be the problem?

Comment: What is the error that you get ?

Comment: No error I just get the full dataset with no filtering

Comment: The problem is that you filter your data here: `datos = tabla[tabla[columna] == criterio]` and then immediately assign it again to `tabla` here: `datos = tabla.drop(columna, axis=1)`. Change the second line to `datos = datos.drop(columna, axis=1)`

Comment: Uff you are certainly , like they say in my country " it is not important to be smart, it is important to have the phone number of the smart guy!!!" thank you so very much cmaher!!!